# How can I concatenate several FLV files into one?

Tags: video, flv

I have a handful of FLV files that are in fact a single sequence. I'd like to combine them into a single file, e.g. part1.flv, part2.flv, part3.flv become final.flv.

What is the easiest way that I can do this without losing video quality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest `mencoder`. This is a part of mplyaer and can be used at command line:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -o final.avi part1.flv part2.flv part3.flv
```

Normally `-oac` and `-ovc` are for special audio and video codecs. In this case the commands says it just should (stream)copy them. The option `-o` gives the name of the output file.

The output could be forced to FLV, but this is currently buggy, and you will get the following message if you try adding `-of lavf`:

> *REMEMBER*: MEncoder's libavformat muxing is presently broken and can generate
>       *INCORRECT* files in the presence of B-frames. Moreover, due to bugs MPlayer
>       will play these INCORRECT files as if nothing were wrong!

According to your comment you got the error:

> Audio format 0x4134504d is incompatible with '-oac copy', please try '-oac pcm' instead or use '-fafmttag' to override it.

According to a [blog entry](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2011/05/mplayermencoder-audio-format-0x4134504d) this is caused by attempting to convert AAC audio. In this case you can try `-oac mp3lame` instead.

Otherwise, add the option `-fafmttag` plus a code for your audio codec. Usually mplayer has a file `etc/codecs.conf`. There you'll find which code maps to which codec. This file does not always exist.

If this doesn't work for you, you can also recode the audio. However this is too complex to describe in this answer. You'll need to look at the manpage or ask another question here.

Comment: thanks! I get `Audio format 0x4134504d is incompatible with '-oac copy', please try '-oac pcm' instead or use '-fafmttag' to override it.` which option should I use?

Comment: I used `-oac pcm` and it worked. This forced the output to be an AVI instead of FLV, which doesn't bother me, but the combined file is 3 times the size of the originals. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might recode the audio part as I describe in an update to my answer.

Comment: avi is preferred because the flv encoder is buggy; I used `-oac mp3lame` based on http://betterlogic.com/roger/2011/05/mplayermencoder-audio-format-0x4134504d/ and it worked, I now have an AVI only slightly larger than the originals